# How to add a WPF custom command

Tags: c#, wpf, commandbinding

I am just learning WPF and C#. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com) tutorial but cannot assign my custom WPF command. I get the following error:

> Schweregrad   Code    Beschreibung    Projekt Datei   Zeile   Unterdrückungszustand
> Fehler  XDG0008 Der Name "Commands" ist im Namespace "clr-namespace:TileMapEditor" nicht vorhanden. TileMapEditor   C:\Entwickl\c#\TileMapEditor\TileMapEditor\MainWindow.xaml  13

But in my code behind in namspace TileMapEditor I definded a static class Commands. Why is it not found?

Here is my YAML:

```
<Window x:Class="TileMapEditor.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TileMapEditor"
        xmlns:self="clr-namespace:TileMapEditor"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TileMapEditor" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.New" CanExecute="NewCommand_CanExecute" Executed="NewCommand_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding Command="ApplicationCommands.Open" CanExecute="OpenCommand_CanExecute" Executed="OpenCommand_Executed" />
        <CommandBinding Command="self:Commands.Exit" CanExecute="OpenCommand_CanExecute" Executed="OpenCommand_Executed" />
    </Window.CommandBindings>
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="_File">
                <MenuItem Command="New" />
                <MenuItem Command="Open" />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Command="Exit" />
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="_Edit">
                <MenuItem Command="Cut" />
                <MenuItem Command="Copy" />
                <MenuItem Command="Paste" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>

        <TextBox AcceptsReturn="True" Name="txtEditor" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

And here my C#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TileMapEditor
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NewCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void NewCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtEditor.Text = "";
        }

        private void OpenCommand_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        private void OpenCommand_Executed(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            txtEditor.Text = "Open";
        }
    }
    public static class Commands
    {
        public static readonly RoutedUICommand Exit = new RoutedUICommand
            (
                "Exit",
                "Exit",
                typeof(MainWindow),
                new InputGestureCollection()
                {
                new KeyGesture(Key.F4, ModifierKeys.Alt)
                }
            );

        //Define more commands here, just like the one above
    }

}
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: I think your problem is due to using a routed UI command in a menu item. You don't need to reference main window at all to just shut the app down. Which is of course what'll happen as you close main window.

Comment: @Andy: No, I don't think it has to do with the menu. The error occurs at the third line of the command bindings in the YAML, even if I remove it from the menu. The shutdown application is only an example. I want to add several user commands, later.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was not related to my code but to Visual Studio. It seems it didn't recognize all changes correctly and creates such missleading error messages. A simple rebuild does the job.
Sorry to bother you. :-)